# Eloqua's update event API endpoint overwrites instead of updating

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

I'm writing a script that will hit the Eloqua API to add a new sessions to an event as per the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-rest-2.0-assets-eventregistration-id-put.html). I'm using the endpoint `/api/REST/2.0/assets/eventRegistration/{id}` from the docs and doing a put request that looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "EventRegistration",
    "id": "131",
        "sessions": [
        {
            "type": "EventSession",
            "id": "46",
            "name": "TEST+PUT+SESSION"
        }
    ]
}
```

But that request overwrites the event and deletes any other sessions that already exist.  Is there a way to tell the api to just add a new session and not overwrite or do I need to do a get request first and then a put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All existing sessions are required when adding new sessions, so you will need to retrieve all sessions to include existing sessions in the PUT.